# Grouped sorting on a JS array

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects with two properties: Name and Hours.

For example:

```
array = [
    {name: "ANDY", hours: 40 }, 
    {name: "ANDY", hours: 50 }, 
    {name: "GREG", hours: 40 },
]
```

For example in my array I would like the result of the sorting to have the Andy with the most hours first, then Andy with slightly less hours, and then Greg because his name comes later alphabetically and so on and so on.

Since the array.sort() function passes two elements of the array to compare i realise this is not the way to go for me but fail to come up with an elegant solution. Please help me out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of objects with multiple field values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379361/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-multiple-field-values-in-javascript)

Comment: @FelixKling: yes, asked 1000 times already, unfortunately most answers so far are lame.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```js
array = [
    {name: "ANDY", hours: 40 }, 
    {name: "GREG", hours: 40 },
    {name: "ANDY", hours: 50 }, 
]

function cmp(x, y) {
  return x > y ? 1 : (x < y ? -1 : 0);
}


array.sort(function(a, b) {
  return cmp(a.name, b.name) || cmp(b.hours, a.hours)
})

console.log(array)
```

If javascript had a [spaceship operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827649/what-is-the-ruby-spaceship-operator) that would be even more elegant. Note that this code is easy to extend to use more properties:

```
ary.sort(function(a, b) {
    return cmp(a.name, b.name) || cmp(a.age, b.age) || cmp(b.hours, a.hours) || ....
})
```

Comment: You're missing semicolons on sort's return statement and the sort functions.

Comment: semicolons are optional

Answer (score 3):

```
var arr = [{
    name: "GREG",
    hours: "40"
}, {
    name: "ANDY",
    hours: "50"
}, {
    name: "ANDY",
    hours: "40"
}];

Array.prototype.sortOn = function(conds){
    this.sort(function(a, b){
        for(var i=0; i < conds.length; i++){
            var c = conds[i].split(" ");
            if(a[c[0]] < b[c[0]]){
                return c[1] == "asc" ? -1:1;
            }
            if(a[c[0]] > b[c[0]]){
                return c[1] == "asc" ? 1:-1;
            }
        }
        return 0;
    });
    return this;
}

arr.sortOn(["name asc", "hours dsc"]);
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is wrong. You cannot return `x > y` from a sorting function.

Comment: Nope, this is the same mistake. You should return -1, 1, or 0, not just 1, -1.

Comment: @thg435. Tried to find a lazy solution. Have corrected considering all conditions. Thanks :)

Answer (score 2):

You can sort by *Name*, then sort elements who have the same name by *Hours*

Example:

```
var array = [{"Name":"ANDY", "Hours":40},
             {"Name":"ANDY", "Hours":50},
             {"Name":"GREG", "Hours":40}];


var sortedArray = array.sort(function(a,b) {
            return (a["Name"] > b["Name"]) ? 1 : -1;
    }).sort(function(a,b) {
            if(a["Name"] == b["Name"])
                return (a["Hours"] < b["Hours"]) ? 1 : -1;
            else 
                return 0;
    });
```

Comment: Javascript sort is not guaranteed to be stable, results may vary across implementations.

Comment: Why are you doing property access via brackets as opposed to dot notation?

Comment: Yeah, both notations work for this particular question. Don't know exactly why I preferred using brackets. I guess it's because it is more generic, if someone have a similar question with properties which contains space characters for example.

Answer (score 2):

```
obj.sort(function(item1,item2) {
  if ( item1.Name < item2.Name )
    return -1;
  if ( item1.Name > item2.Name )
    return 1;
  return item1.Hours - item2.Hours;
});
```