# is it possible to sort a sorted array based on another object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I am sorting this type of array by genre:

```
const bands = [ 
  { genre: 'Rap', band: 'Migos', albums: 2},
  { genre: 'Pop', band: 'Coldplay', albums: 4, awards: 10},
  { genre: 'Pop', band: 'xxx', albums: 4, awards: 11},
  { genre: 'Pop', band: 'yyyy', albums: 4, awards: 12},
  { genre: 'Rock', band: 'Breaking zzzz', albums: 1}
  { genre: 'Rock', band: 'Breaking Benjamins', albums: 1}
];
```

With this:

```
function compare(a, b) {
  // Use toUpperCase() to ignore character casing
  const genreA = a.genre.toUpperCase();
  const genreB = b.genre.toUpperCase();

  let comparison = 0;
  if (genreA > genreB) {
    comparison = 1;
  } else if (genreA < genreB) {
    comparison = -1;
  }
  return comparison;
}
```

As describe [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/sort-an-array-of-objects-in-javascript/)
But after sorting by genre, I also want to sort it by number of albums.Is it possible? TIA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Grouped sorting on a JS array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164078/grouped-sorting-on-a-js-array)

Comment: How is the title related to the question? "sort based on another object" vs. "sort by multiple properties"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript, how do you sort an array on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784230/javascript-how-do-you-sort-an-array-on-multiple-columns)

Comment: That's I what I really meant but I just find the right words earlier. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

```
function compare(a, b) {
// Use toUpperCase() to ignore character casing
const genreA = a.genre.toUpperCase();
const genreB = b.genre.toUpperCase();

return genreA.localeCompare(genreB) || a.albums-
b.albums;
}
```

I shortified your code to genreA.localeCompare(genreB). If it is 0, the genres are equal, and we'll therefore compare by the number of albums.

This if 0 take ... instead is provided by the OR operator...

Answer (score 0):

Sure, after you are done doing whatever you need to do with the first array. Assuming you don't want to modify your first array, you can make a copy by using slice. Then you can sort by album number. Let me know if this helps

```js
const bands = [{
    genre: 'Rap',
    band: 'Migos',
    albums: 2
  },
  {
    genre: 'Pop',
    band: 'Coldplay',
    albums: 4,
    awards: 10
  },
  {
    genre: 'Pop',
    band: 'xxx',
    albums: 4,
    awards: 11
  },
  {
    genre: 'Pop',
    band: 'yyyy',
    albums: 4,
    awards: 12
  },
  {
    genre: 'Rock',
    band: 'Breaking zzzz',
    albums: 1
  },
  {
    genre: 'Rock',
    band: 'Breaking Benjamins',
    albums: 1
  }
];


var sortedAlbumNumber = bands.slice();

sortedAlbumNumber.sort((a, b) => a['albums'] - b['albums']);

console.log(sortedAlbumNumber);
```