# JavaScript: group items by a key, sort items within(!) the groups by another key - how?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, grouping

in my results Students should be grouped(!) by Room-Id and then, within the group, sorted by age.

**Results grouped/sorted by Room:**

```
Name      | R | Age  
-------------------
Student 2 | 1 | 22  
Student 4 | 1 | 25  
Student 3 | 3 | 21  
Student 6 | 3 | 27  
Student 1 | 5 | 29 <- Wrong, should be: Student 5, Room 5, Age 23 
Student 5 | 5 | 23 <- Wrong, should be: Student 1, Room 5, Age 29
```

My **current code** (JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n9KNx/):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
/* add students */
var students = new Array();
students.push({ name: "Student 1", room_id: 5, age: 29 });
students.push({ name: "Student 2", room_id: 1, age: 22 });
students.push({ name: "Student 3", room_id: 3, age: 21 });
students.push({ name: "Student 4", room_id: 1, age: 25 });
students.push({ name: "Student 5", room_id: 5, age: 23 });
students.push({ name: "Student 6", room_id: 3, age: 27 });

/* sort by room_id */
students.sort(function(a, b) {
    return ((a.room_id < b.room_id) ? -1 : ((a.room_id > b.room_id) ? 1 : 0));
});

/* FIXME: sort by age without changing the room order */
/* ... code ... */

/* build HTML output */
var html = '<table>';
html += '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Room</th><th>Age</th></tr>';
for (var i = 0; i < students.length; i++) {
    html += '<tr><td>'+ students[i].name +'</td><td>'+ students[i].room_id +'</td>    <td>'+ students[i].age +'</td></tr>';
}
html += '</table>';

$("#students").html(html);
</script>

<div id="students">...</div>
```

How would you sort the students by age within each group? I added the code on JSFiddle, feel free to play with it!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to sort an array of objects with multiple field values in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379361/how-to-sort-an-array-of-objects-with-multiple-field-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The sort function needed to be expanded to cover when the rooms are equal.  When the rooms are equal we then compare the age.

```
students.sort(function(a, b) {
    if(a.room_id < b.room_id){
        return -1;  
    }else if(a.room_id > b.room_id){
        return 1;
    }else{
        if(a.age < b.age){
           return -1
        }else if(a.age > b.age){
          return 1;
        }else{
          return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/n9KNx/1/

Comment: So this returns `undefined` if they're equal?

Comment: Great solution, to explain how sorting function works. I appreciate the lengthy answer to short answer for the sake of readability. Keep it simple and awesome!

Answer (score 5):

Since you're sorting on numbers, you don't need to do [three-way comparisons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-way_comparison) but just can compute the difference. The solution looks then like this:

```
students.sort(function(a, b) {
    return (a.room_id - b.room_id) || (a.age - b.age);
});
```

…and does exactly the same thing as the lengthy snippets from the other answers :-)

Comment: I had a feeling there's a better idiom than my cascade of trinaries.

Answer (score 1):

```
students.sort(function(a, b) {
    return ((a.room_id < b.room_id) ? -1 :
              ((a.room_id > b.room_id) ? 1 :
                 ((a.age < b.age) ? -1 :
                    ((a.age > b.age) ? 1 : 0))));
});
```