# elasticsearch sort by price with currency

Tags: laravel, elasticsearch

I have data

```
{
  "id": 1000,
  "price": "99,01USA", 
},
{
  "id": 1001,
  "price": "100USA", 
},
{
  "id": 1002,
  "price": "780USA", 
},
{
  "id": 1003,
  "price": "20USA", 
},
```

How I sort order by price (ASC , DESC)

Comment: what do you need? elasticsearch query or php code?

Comment: According to my understating this should be array of objects
[
{
  "id": 1000,
  "price": "99,01USA", 
},
{
  "id": 1001,
  "price": "100USA", 
}
]

Comment: I am using PHP to seach on Elastic Seach

Comment: @mr.BaoNC, So sorting on numeric value is easy in elastic search ... but in your case it is a string, could it be possible to modify your data in `price` to make it into a number ?
If this is not a viable solution .... this is going to be quite tricky I am afraid

Comment: You can put price-as-a-number in a separate field and use that for sorting if you need prices to look exactly like if your example.

Answer (score 1):

You can alter it a little to parse price to integer and then sort it

You can create a dynamic sort function that sorts objects by their value that you pass:

```
function dynamicSort(property) {
    var sortOrder = 1;
    if(property[0] === "-") {
        sortOrder = -1;
        property = property.substr(1);
    }
    return function (a,b) {
        /* next line works with strings and numbers, 
         * and you may want to customize it to your needs
         */
        var result = (a[property] < b[property]) ? -1 : (a[property] > b[property]) ? 1 : 0;
        return result * sortOrder;
    }
}
```

So you can have an array of objects like this:

```
var People = [
    {Name: "Name", Surname: "Surname"},
    {Name:"AAA", Surname:"ZZZ"},
    {Name: "Name", Surname: "AAA"}
];
```

...and it will work when you do:

```
People.sort(dynamicSort("Name"));
People.sort(dynamicSort("Surname"));
People.sort(dynamicSort("-Surname"));
```

Actually this already answers the question. Below part is written because many people contacted me, complaining that [it doesn't work with multiple parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11379361).

### Multiple Parameters

You can use the function below to generate sort functions with multiple sort parameters.

```
function dynamicSortMultiple() {
    /*
     * save the arguments object as it will be overwritten
     * note that arguments object is an array-like object
     * consisting of the names of the properties to sort by
     */
    var props = arguments;
    return function (obj1, obj2) {
        var i = 0, result = 0, numberOfProperties = props.length;
        /* try getting a different result from 0 (equal)
         * as long as we have extra properties to compare
         */
        while(result === 0 && i < numberOfProperties) {
            result = dynamicSort(props[i])(obj1, obj2);
            i++;
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Which would enable you to do something like this:

```
People.sort(dynamicSortMultiple("Name", "-Surname"));
```

#### Subclassing Array

For the lucky among us who can use ES6, which allows extending the native objects:

```
class MyArray extends Array {
    sortBy(...args) {
        return this.sort(dynamicSortMultiple(...args));
    }
}
```

That would enable this:

```
MyArray.from(People).sortBy("Name", "-Surname");
```

Comment: Thank Mr CYBERKING40
but I want seach on elastic seach